# How to set React's PUBLIC_URL during runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, webpack

I have a CRA fresh project, this project is going to be used on a site that renders multiple plugins inside an "iframe", serving them using a proxy which I can't figure out the URL before instantiating the plugin.

To get the location of the plugin, they provide us with a function called `getOriginProxyUrl()` that returns us a path name (something like `/plugins/plugin-name/random-code-ID/random-domain/`).

My issue comes during the load of react chunks under this configuration, index.html loads correctly, but `bundle.js` & `chunks[..].js` files returns me a 404 since the URL is trying to point to `/static/js/...` instead of `/plugins/plugin-name/random-code-ID/random-domain/static/js/...`

Since I'm using CRA, I investigated and I found that setting an .env variable called `PUBLIC_URL` would help me to set this URL correctly, I tested it by hardcoding the publicpath that `getOriginProxyUrl()` function returns and it allowed me to use my React application in their "iframe" without issues.

My question is, Is there a way to set this PUBLIC_URL during runtime (Perhaps in the index.html file) instead of setting an .env file or env variable?

I tried also setting `__webpack_public_path__` as described in [Change Webpack's publicPath on the fly](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/change-webpacks-publicpath-on-the-fly-8c7166a031f9), but it only allowed me to change the URL of the assets (images & icons) and didn't work for the static chunks

I hope that my questions is clear enough to describe my issue hehe, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at the following

1. [react env](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env)
2. [Nginx compatible solution](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I'm not able to use env variables as I don't know the URL where the proxy is going to send me the data :/

Comment: Hey, if you use the Nginx compatible solution approach, you could have a startup script that calls getOriginProxy, and uses that to set a variable in a js file used in your app. In fact your solution would be very similar except that instead of env vars you call a function.

Comment: @lex thank you. If you found the answer helpful please upvote it and mark it as the answer so others see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use environment and use process.env in the webpack as global variable and use it in the output object of your webpack config

```
const ASSET_PATH = process.env.ASSET_PATH || '/';

export default {
  output: {
    publicPath: ASSET_PATH,
  },

  plugins: [
    // This makes it possible for us to safely use env vars on our code
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.ASSET_PATH': JSON.stringify(ASSET_PATH),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Or on the fly

```
__webpack_public_path__ = process.env.ASSET_PATH;
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer, unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for, this only helps in the assets side (images, fonts, etc, as I mentioned in the question), my issue is with the static bundle files (the js files that have all the react code) :/ I'm not able to use env variables as I don't know the URL where the proxy is going to send me the data